# Watin Firefox SetAttributeValue

Tags: firefox, automation, watin, jssh

I'm trying to change images on a website using Watin (FireFox 3.6).
The code worked fine using IE, but after installing Windows 8.1, Watin doesn't work at all on IE 11, so I switched to FireFox.

The following code causes a FireFoxException/jssh error: invalid label

```
img.SetAttributeValue("src", "http://picload.org/image/X/X.png");
```

The image exists, and it's Src attribute contains a valid URL.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance. I'm switching to more reliable methods like curl, so there is no need to advice me to use Watin alternatives.

Comment: A workaround using eval apparently doesn't work, it tells me $ is not defined, although jQuery is clearly loaded on the page.

Comment: It looks like `img.Uri` has both a getter and a setter. Maybe try `img.Uri = new Uri(...)`?